# Evaluate expression in ggplot with paste and deparse functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write this bit of code in my ggplot block.

```
ggtitle(expression(atop(bold(paste0("Control rates Vs Mean yield for " , deparse(substitute(field)))), atop(italic("(Anova:TukeyHSD)"), ""))))
```

It is either generating this error

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
```

and If it works, the plot will have title as it is: `paste0("Control rates Vs Mean yield for ", deparse(substitute(field)))`

How do I properly write this ggtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can use `bquote`

```
library(ggplot2)
field <- "Some Variable"
ggplot() +
    ggtitle(bquote(atop(bold(paste("Control rates Vs Mean yield for ", 
           .(field))), atop(italic("(Anova:TukeyHSD)")))))
```

[image]